# Проверка: является ли элемент последним в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Допустим, есть список:

```py
l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
```

Список может содержать повторяющиеся `case sensitive` значения.

Необходимо перебрать элементы данного списка с задержкой между итерациями без использования `enumerate` и других счетчиков (**UPDATE**). Во время итерации по этому списку проверить, является ли текущий элемент последним в списке. Если последний - без задержки продолжить выполнение скрипта.

**Пример:**

```py
import time

def check(seq: list) -> None:
    for elem in seq:
        print(elem)
        time.sleep(1)

l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
check(l)
```

Как я проверяю сейчас:

```py
time.sleep(1) if seq.index(elem)+1 != len(seq) else print('This is last!')
```

**Проблема** в том, что если значение последнего элемента не уникально, то `print('This is last!')` не будет достигнуто:

```py
import time

def check(seq: list) -> None:
    for elem in seq:
        print(elem)
        time.sleep(1) if seq.index(elem)+1 != len(seq) else print('This is last!')

l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
check(l)

l.sort()
print('\nAfter sort:')
check(l)
```

**UPDATE**: использование каких-либо счетчиков нежелательно.

Comment: 1) for с индексом 2) count+=1 пока не достигнет len(list)

Comment: @MBo забыл указать что без индексов. Про `enumarate` написал, а про индексы забыл

Comment: Тогда второе с доп. счётчиком. Ещё вариант - задержка **перед** print, в первый раз игнорируется

Comment: @MBo я может не правильно понял про индексы. Вы имели в виду решение подобное тому, что указал ghostik2005 ?

Comment: Да, как у Ghostik. Вариант с задержкой перед print требует только логического (boolean) флага

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может с помощью слайсов?

```
import time

def check(seq: list) -> None:
    for elem in seq[:-1]:
        print(elem)
        time.sleep(1)

    print(seq[-1], ' - This is last')

l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']

check(l)
```

Comment: `print(elem)` - это просто пример обработки элемента. Последний элемент тоже должен быть обработан, но после его обработки `time.sleep(1)` не должно выполняться. Обрабатывать отдельно последний элемент вне цикла считаю лишним загромождением кода

Comment: @TheMarhang Обработка должна выполняться именно в теле цикла и ее нельзя применить отдельно к последнему элементу?

Comment: да, в цикле ~70 строк работы с элементом

Comment: @TheMarhang А что если вывести код, отвечающий за обработку элемента, в отдельную функцию?

Comment: В процессе :) после преобразования данное решение отлично подойдет, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

def check(seq: list) -> None:
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        print(seq[i])
        time.sleep(1) if i+1 != len(seq) else print('This is last!')

l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
check(l)

l.sort()
print('\nAfter sort:')
check(l)
```

Comment: Спасибо, такое решение тоже подходит

Answer (score 1):

С использованием итератора:

```py
import time

def check(seq: list) -> None:
    if len(seq) > 0:
        it = iter(seq) # Получаем итератор
        prev_item = next(it) # Получаем нулевой элемент последовательности
        try:
            while True:
                print(prev_item)
                next_item = next(it) # Пытаемся получить следующий элемент последовательности
                time.sleep(1) # Если элемент удачно получили (не сработало исключение)
                prev_item = next_item
        except StopIteration: # Если следующего элемента последовательности нет
            print("This is last!")


l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
check(l)


l.sort()
print('\nAfter sort:')
check(l)
```

Comment: Использование итераторов не оптимально с точки зрения использования памяти, разве нет? Значением же может быть не только строка, но и другой объект. А тут нам приходится хранить одновременно 2 элемента последовательности

Comment: 1. У Вас в вопросе ни слова про память. 2. Это питон, он оперирует ссылками, поэтому одновременно хранится 2 **ссылки** на элементы последовательности, а если Вам жалко памяти на один объект (итератор) и три ссылки (на итератор, на элементы), то это уже экономия на спичках, на этом стоит экономить только если Вы пишете на каком-нибудь ассемблере.

Comment: Все время забываю, что в питоне хранятся ссылки, а не сами объекты. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, простейшим вариантом будет использование доп. счётчика:

```py
import time

def check(seq: list) -> None:
    counter = 0
    for elem in seq:
        print(elem)
        time.sleep(1) if counter+1 < len(seq) else print('This is last!')
        counter += 1

l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
check(l)

l.sort()
print('\nAfter sort:')
check(l)
```

Comment: Вопрос обновлен. Без использования счетчика как-то возможно?

Comment: @TheMarhang Сейчас подумаю...

Answer (score 0):

А не проще реализовать через `pop()`?

```
l = ['hello', 'world', 'human', 'world', 'World']

while len(l)>1:
    print(l.pop(0))    
    print(l)
```

выдаст:

```
hello
['world', 'human', 'world', 'World']
world
['human', 'world', 'World']
human
['world', 'World']
world
['World']
```

То есть, после завершения цикла `while` у вас гарантировано в списке останется последний элемент.

Comment: А если мне необходимо дальше работать с этим списком? `pop()` - не вариант

Comment: ну так используйте копию. вы же все равно отдельную функцию пишите.